# I am getting null values from database.when i select email in my dao class

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

Here is my DaoImpl class.

```
 public DealUser findByUserEmail(String email) 
        {
            session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

            Query query=session.createQuery("from tbldealusers where email=:email");



            query.setParameter("email", dealuser.getEmail());
            List list=query.list();

         return dealuser;
        }
```

I am calling this method in  restService

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/find/{email}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public  DealUser findByUserId(@PathVariable(value = "email") String email)
{


    return userService.findByUserId(email);
}
```

I am getting null values like this

{"userid":0,"email":null,"password":null,"typeofuserluid":0,"is_deleted":false,"profiles":[]}

Thanks in advance for your valueable suggestions

Comment: where is the select statement?

Comment: Query query=session.createQuery("from tbldealusers where email=:email");  here i am selecting the statement know

Comment: you should pass the email value from the method  parameter(findByUserEmail(String email)) rather than dealeruser.getEmail()

Comment: I am attaching the email value to the url. like this  http://localhost:8090/SaveDollar/rest/users/find/"abc@gmail.com"

Comment: you should get rid of "" just ..../find/email@address

Comment: tbldealusers should be the name of your entity class since you are using an hibernate query. It should be Tbldealusers

Comment: then how can i find email from the table by attaching to the url?

Comment: @zeroke you are exactly right...but i am getting this error org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: DealUser is not mapped [from DealUser where email=:email]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'tbldealusers' should be the name of your entity class since you are using an hibernate query. It should be 'Tbldealusers'.

session.createQuery(..) uses HQL (Hibernate Query Language). according to the [session createQuery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/classic/Session.html)

According to the docs this method is deprecated.